# MVC 4 LINQ statments doesn't work with not english

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, unicode, arabic

i have this statement in my controller

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                buildings = buildings.Where(s => s.name.Contains(searchString));
            }
```

it works perfectly when the `searchString` is in english, however, when i want to use arabic words to search, i got empty results. why PLease?

what should i do to work with not english words in the linq statemtns?

#### note

that i can see the arabic words in my database

#### note 2

the fields in my database from type `vnarchar`

Comment: I can imagine that this might be because Contains is culture-insensitive. Can you try `s.name.IndexOf(searchString) >= 0`?

Comment: contains gives me the results that contains not EXAXT, but index gives me the EXACT, i need that just contains. got me?

Comment: You can use the `SQL Server Profiler` to get `SQL` that `EF` generates.

Comment: @VyacheslavVolkov kindly giev me an example

Comment: You can read about the `SQL Server Profiler` at [this link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms181091(v=sql.105).aspx).

Comment: How do you connect to the DB? Do you use an ORM? EF, LINQ to SQL, NHibernate... ? ASP.NET MVC has nothing to do with it, except that the VS templates reference EF by default. If you use any of those frameworks, please give us your ORM configuration. There might be something wrong with it.

Comment: Also keep in mind that Contains() only gives you EXACT string matches, including lower / upper case, whitespaces etc.

Comment: @chris what should i do to use instead of contains to get the 'contains' ?

Comment: What do you mean by "get the 'contains'"? If you want to check for exact substrings, Contains() is correct. If you want to do e.g. case insensitive comparison, you can use IndexOf() with the StringComparison parameter, as sugessted in David Brossard's answer. It all depends on what it is exactly that you are trying to do - that's not really clear. You still haven't even told us if you are using EF, LINQ to SQL etc...

Answer (score 0):

What is `buildings`?

If `buildings` is of type `IEnumerable` (not `IQueryable`) then you can try -

```
buildings.Where(s => s.name.IndexOf(searchString, StringComparison.InvariantCulture) != -1)
```